# Moving average in pivot tables in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I'm trying to build a pivot table where one column shows the rolling average of the last 6 cells in another column but I can't get it to work.

Any hints where to start?

Answer (score 2):

Like @pnuts said, don't do it inside a pivot table. In a pivot table, you should not think in terms of rows and columns, but in terms of dimensions and measures. Depending on the current arrangement of dimensions of measures, as well as the filters on the dimensions (visible or invisible), the moving average could show very wrong results.

Instead, construct your moving average as a column associated with the pivot source range.

If you must do it from inside a pivot table, you can try using the GETPIVOTDATA() function, but I predict the exact expression could get very convoluted.